# Is there a way to rename multiple df columns in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiple-columns

I'm trying to rename multiple columns in a dataframe to certain dates with Python.

Currently, the columns are as such: 2016-04, 2016-05, 2016-06....

I would like the columns to read: April2016, May2016, June2016...

There are around 40 columns. I am guessing a for loop would be the most efficient way to do this, but I'm relatively new to Python and not sure how to concatenate the column names correctly.

Comment: There might be some way. It **completely** depends on the library/data structure you are using to store the data. You did not mention anything about this. Please specify which library you are using and add the appropriate tag to your question

Comment: is your dataframe the pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use loops or comprehensions along with a month dictionary to split, reorder, and replace the string column names

```
#in your case this would be cols=df.columns
cols=['2016-04', '2016-05', '2016-06']
rpl={'04':'April','05':'May','06':'June'}

cols=[\
 ''.join(\
         [rpl[i.split('-')[1]],
              i.split('-')[0]]) \
 for i in cols]

cols
['April2016', 'May2016', 'June2016']

#then you would assign it back with df.columns = cols
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a for loop for this? I have dates starting in April2016, but going each month until March2019.

Comment: The only thing you need to hard code is the `rpl` dictionary to map numeric months to text months. Then it's as simple as `df.columns=[''.join([rpl[i.split('-')[1]], i.split('-')[0]]) for i in df.columns]`

Comment: Thanks Anderson! I guess my question pertains to what happens if I were to download additional, updated, data that now had months past March2019? I'm wondering if there is a way to make this code consistent to work regardless of the number of months I have in the df.

Comment: This does work for any number of dates, provided you don't suddenly introduce a 13th month in a given year lol. The only hard-coded piece is the dict that maps 01 to January, 02-February...12 to December. The rest is dynamic string manipulations. Go ahead and create a sample df with dates as far out as you want and it still ought to work, as long as the string format is the same.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't share your dataframe so I used basic dataframe to explain how to get month is given date.I supposed your dataframe likes:

```
d = {'dates': ['2016-04', '2016-05','2016-06']} #just 3 of them
```

so all code :

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
d = {'dates': ['2016-04', '2016-05','2016-06']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    get_date= row['dates'].split('-')
    get_month = get_date[1]
    month = datetime.date(1900, int(get_month), 1).strftime('%B')
    print (month+get_date[0])
```

OUTPUT :

```
2016April
2016May
2016June
```

Comment: OP specifies column names, not indices